# Express: Best way to share a JS config file between client and server

Tags: node.js, configuration-files, express

I have a `config.js` file that has all my app settings inside it. Some of these settings need to be shared with front-end scripts as well as back-end.

I have some confidential variables that I don't want to be exposed to the front-end though. Do any NodeJS/ExpressJS wizz kids have any good solutions to this?

Do you keep your common config data in a `/public` location and confidential server-side data separate above the exposed `/public` folder?

*Thanks guys*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [express-expose](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-expose) to share (or 'expose') data from the server to the client works pretty well. As Raynos said, I would keep confidential variables as environment variables and then you may be able to safely expose all of your settings.

Or you can do something like create a 'shared' object in your settings. Like this:

```
app.set('shared', {
    setting1: mydata
  , setting2: new OAuth(...)
  , setting3: { ... }
});
```

Which allows you to access the settings as `app.setting.shared.setting1` on the server and then you can `app.expose(app.setting.shared)` so your client side JS can access the same object.

Comment: This is a great module thanks for the heads up. Just what I needed :)

Comment: shouldn't `app.set('shared':` be `app.set('shared',)`?

Comment: Thanks for note @ArvindSridharan I just updated it now.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use [express-expose](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-expose) to share your variables with the frontend or you can use [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) and share your settings in a module.

Answer (score 1):

> I have some confidential variables that I don't want to be exposed to the front-end though.

I generally have confidential variables defined in environment variables. This also solves the problem of committing / hard coding these variables in version control.

Comment: I can't seem to get the Environmental Variable stuff working in Windows which is annoying. Any ideas?

Comment: @pagewil I edit mine through the gui interface in win7. Works for me.

Comment: Ah so any of those vars are directly accessible from within you app? If so that is pretty awesome!

Comment: @pagewil yes. `process.env[name]`

Answer (score 0):

There is also [express-state](https://github.com/yahoo/express-state) from Yahoo, it lets you

> share configuration and state data of an Express app with the
>   client-side via JavaScript

It is well documented and the readme contains a lot of useful examples